# Access Group By Month Names Using Format Function

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am Unable to Sort the Order By  by Month names in MS Access Database

I am Using the Format Function to retrieve Month Name (If I use MonthName(Month(date)) Function The Query is Executing at Access DB(but when I am trying to Use the Same Query from My Application I am getting Errors

```
My Query is
```

This is My Query(Code )`Used all the Functions of Format But I am Unable to Order By MonthNames`

```
SELECT Format(date ,"mmmm") as MonthName,
 Sum(Rojnamchatable.asal1) AS SumOfasal1,
 Sum(Rojnamchatable.chaat1) AS SumOfchaat1,
 SumOfasal1+SumOfchaat1 AS TotalBiri1,
 Sum(Rojnamchatable.asal2) AS SumOfasal2, 
Sum(Rojnamchatable.chaat2) AS SumOfchaat2, 
SumOfasal2+SumOfchaat2 AS TotalBiri2,

GROUP BY Format(date ,"mmmm")
ORDER BY Format(date ,"mmmm")


I am Getting Data Perfectly But I am unable to get Order By Month Name
(i.e Jan ,Feb ,March)

I Even Used Format(date,"mm") Function If I Use that I am getting Erors

So Please try to Solve My Issue

I Spent 2 days for this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding the month (number) column but not displaying it?

```
SELECT 
    Format([date] ,"mmmm") as MonthName,
    Sum(Rojnamchatable.asal1) AS SumOfasal1,
    Sum(Rojnamchatable.chaat1) AS SumOfchaat1,
    SumOfasal1+SumOfchaat1 AS TotalBiri1,
    Sum(Rojnamchatable.asal2) AS SumOfasal2, 
    Sum(Rojnamchatable.chaat2) AS SumOfchaat2, 
    SumOfasal2 + SumOfchaat2 AS TotalBiri2,
FROM 
    yourTableName
GROUP BY 
    Format([date] ,"mmmm"), Month(date)
ORDER BY 
    Month([date])
```

Please note I have enclosed date in [], this is because of the fact Date is a reserved word and should not be used as a column/field name.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please click the 'Green Tick' to mark it as answer, so other could be of benefit.

Comment: Done !  Right now your help is Countless price for me !

Comment: Glad to be of help ! :) Good luck